# Emacs python nested loop indentation issue

Tags: python, emacs, indentation

I am new to emacs, and I am trying to write a nested for loop but the second for loop has no auto indentation when I pressed ENTER/RETURN. As shown in the picture below, where the highlighted mouse key is still at the same indentation level with the first for loop. Is there any easier way to solve this?

[image]

I am pretty new to emacs, so if you could kindly elaborate the steps of solutions, if would be wonderful.

Comment: It could be that your Emacs does not start the `python-mode`. Look [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs) for an introduction, and [here](https://realpython.com/emacs-the-best-python-editor/) for a more complex guide.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem by starting with `emacs -q`, which ignores all of your customizations.  If the problem goes away (it probably will), it's in your customizations, and you can try to narrow it down and ask more targeted questions.

Comment: But also, I see an unclosed paren in your code, which is probably breaking the indentation.  Try `show-paren-mode` to highlight matching and mismatched parens.